# Pushing a single table to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, deployment

I am aware of the `heroku pg:push` command which pushes an entire database up to Heroku.

Now that I am launching my product, I would like to be able to push up only a specific table that contains information collected locally without overwriting existing tables (such as users).

Is there a command that enables me to only push specific tables to heroku?

Comment: Try `heroku db:push --tables <table1>, <table2>` ..Let me know the result.

Comment: Umm [this feature](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku) has been deprecated. I found the command from [here](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/4/21/supporting_big_data_part_1).

Comment: Yep, was about to mention that, sadly. A similar option for `pg:push` does not exist.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My suggestion is to use PostgreSQL dump/restore capabilities directly using the [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) and [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/backup-dump.html) commands.

With `pg_dump` you can dump a specific table from your local database

```
$ pg_dump --data-only --table=products sourcedb > products.sql
```

Then grab the Heroku PostgreSQL connection string from the configs

```
$ heroku config | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL

# example
# postgres://user3123:passkja83kd8@ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6212/db982398
```

and restore the table in the remote database, using the information retrieved from Heroku.

```
$ psql -h ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p 6212 -U user3123 db982398 < products.sql
```

You will need to customize the `-p`, `-h` and `-U` parameters, as well as the database name. The password will be prompted by `psql`.

You can also use the [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) to filter a dump and restore the table, but I personally prefer `psql`.

Note that Heroku is recommending the use of PostgreSQL tools in several documentations, such as [Importing and Exporting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) for large data, or whenever the provided CLI commands don't cover specific cases like the one in this question.

Comment: Appreciate the thorough response! Will award the bounty when able.

Comment: Does `db982398 < products.sql` replace the table or append to it?

Comment: To get the credentials run `$ heroku pg:credentials:url`

Comment: For instance if this is my config URL `postgres://user3123:passkja83kd8@ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6212/db982398` then password is `passkja83kd8`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote script which extracts DB url from heroku. Then it dumps single tables from production and restores them on development/localhost. Run it like this:

```
rake production_to_development:run\['users;news;third_table',my-sushi-app\]
```

Code:

```
namespace :production_to_development do
  task :run, [:tables, :app] => [:environment] do |t, args|
    tables = args["tables"].split(';')
    database_url = nil
    Bundler.with_clean_env { database_url = `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL --app=#{args["app"]}` }

    require 'addressable/uri'
    uri = Addressable::URI.parse(database_url)
    remote_database = uri.path[1,uri.path.length-2] # there is \n at the end of the path!

    tables.each do |table|
      backup_file = "tmp/#{table}.backup"
      #bin_dir = "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin"
      bin_dir = ""

      dump_command = "PGPASSWORD=#{uri.password} #{bin_dir}/pg_dump --file \"#{backup_file}\" --host \"#{uri.host}\" --port \"#{uri.port}\" --username \"#{uri.user}\" --no-password --verbose --format=c --blobs --table \"public.#{table}\" \"#{remote_database}\""
      `#{dump_command}`
      `psql -U 'root' -d my_table -c 'drop table if exists #{table}'`
      `pg_restore -d my_table --no-owner  #{backup_file}`
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you just need a single database table with its locally created data pushed to your Rails production app. Maybe this is a simplistic approach, but you could create a migration for your table and then populate using `db/seeds.rb`.

After you've populated the seeds.rb file and pushed your repo to heroku:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Also, if your local table has a ton of data and you're using Rails 4, check out the seed dump gem: https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump. This will take your existing db data and map it to the seed format.

Comment: The table already exists on the deployed app. I assume I could seed just that single table but doing that for every other table I want to upload would be very time consuming.