# Update single Heroku PostgreSQL table from SQL file

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I tried to import a sql file into 1 table in Heroku postgresql.

I followed the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28286678/3498996

```
# Dump specific table data
pg_dump --data-only --table=products sourcedb > products.sql

# Get connection info
heroku config | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL

# example
# postgres://user3123:passkja83kd8@ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6212/db982398

# Import file
psql -h ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p 6212 -U user3123 db982398 < products.sql
```

However I encountered this error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "products_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY products, line 1
```

This means that the row exists, therefore unable to copy.

I thought of the following

```
ALTER TABLE products RENAME to original_products
CREATE TABLE products;
# import data, and drop original_products after checking
DROP TABLE original_products
```

However, I don't know what are the potential side effects. I prefer a solution that don't drop any table.

What I want is to replace the entire products table with the sql file data. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You will have to drop the old table or delete the old data at some point. This should answer your question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100779/how-to-atomically-replace-table-data-in-postgresql

Comment: depends on what you want to get. **copy** of the table from the file or **merge** of two source.
in any case, you should not drop before you will completely sure. You can drop your table at any time, after day,week,year.